# Unable to build scipy with mkl on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, scipy, intel-mkl

I am trying to build numpy and scipy on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 with Intel MKL.

I have installed all the prerequisites. 
The INTEL C++ complier and the Fortran compiler verision are all 2011 sp1 10.319 and MKL is the version within it.

I am following the installation instruction from [INTEL's website](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/numpy-scipy-with-mkl/).

I have successfully build and installed numpy.

When building scipy I encounted the problem as follows:

```
error: could note create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy': Permission denied
```

when I try to put sudo in front of the install line, I got:

```
numpy.distutils.fcompiler.CompilerNotFound: intelem: f90 nor f77
```

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm no expert but it seems to me that you might need to explicitly tell the SciPy build script to use `ifort` instead of hunting for `f90` or `f77`. NumPy, As far as I know, doesn't need a fortran compiler so there were no issues there. If you don't mind using the GNU set of compilers, just hit `sudo apt-get install gfortran` (or whatever it is for 12.04) and I think it will install. You won't be able to use Intel's compiler though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to specify that you want to use the intel compiler for *both* numpy and scipy. (Numpy doesn't require a fortran compiler, but it will use it, if present.)

Try doing:

```
python setup.py build --fcompiler=ifort
sudo python setup.py install
```

(or something similar) for both numpy and scipy.